# How do i find the second largest element among given collection of numbers?

Tags: c, loops

Without using an array, I am trying to do this. what is wrong with my code?

n is the number of elements,a is the first element(assumed to be maximum initially), b stores new element every time and sec variable stores the second-largest element. Numbers are all positive. This is from an online contest.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int main() { 
    int i,a,b,max,n,sec;
    scanf("%d",&n); 
    scanf("%d",&a); 
    max=a;
    while(n-1!=0) { 
        scanf("%d",&b);
        if(b>max) {
            sec=max;
            max=b;
        }

        else if(b<max && b>sec)
            sec=b;
        else{}
        n--;
    }  

    printf("%d",sec);

    return 0; 
}
```

getting wrong answers in some test cases( i don't know )

Comment: `sec` is not initialized. Hence, the 2nd test is undefined as long as `b` isn't `> max`. (Assumption.)

Comment: Please provide at least the part of your assignment which describes the input range and make a [mcve] of your code.

Comment: Can the array hold two identical numbers? What happens then?

Comment: @Yunnosch No, I cannot. That's why _(Assumption.)_ ;-)

Comment: int i,a,b,max,n,sec; everything is defined inside main()

Comment: As a suggestion, when running this kind of tests, always print out what the value of max, sec, and b are at each cycle. You never know when one of your assumptions might be wrong, but this way you'll notice.

Comment: Tip: Test your code against the values `1 2 2` (+ whatever you need first, I assume it's number of numbers to read). Expected result is `2`.

Comment: Please provide a MCVE instead of describing code. Do so by [edit]ing your question.

Comment: Please, make it a [mcve] which can be copy/pasted in an online compiler. (I believe my assumption was correct.)

Comment: @Scheff Missed that detail (and you did not edit...) My mistake.

Comment: https://textuploader.com/1rj70 here's the code

Comment: Please provide a MCVE by editing your question and showing the code directly here as text, not as link.

Comment: Proper formatting would improve code readability tremendously. Recommendation: place spaces around operators, have space after comma, and for if/else chains: if one branch uses braces, use them for all of, even if one consists just of a single instruction. Many coding conventions mandate *always* placing braces. And many consider [Allman style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Allman_style) better readable than the variants keeping one brace at the same line.

Comment: "int i,a,b,max,n,sec; everything is defined inside main()" and not initialised @Scheff You won.

Comment: What's wrong with [edit]? ;-)

Comment: A good answer would name a test case which fails and explain why. Are you making one @Scheff?

Comment: nisshar Please take the [tour].

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*   2) use meaningful variable and function names.  single letter names are meaningless and (generally) should not be used.

Comment: Overall, this seems to be from a online code challenge.  1) that should be mentioned in the question.  2) we 'should not' give you the complete answer to a online code challenge as that would result in our code being submitted as yours.  I.E. a falsification

Answer (score 2):

Lets look at the input

```
2 4 3
```

Two is the number of inputs.
4 ends up in `max`.
3 ends up in `b`.
`b` is not greater than `max`, the if does not do anything.
`b` is less than max, but `b` is not necessarily greater than `sec`,
because sec at this point can be anything - whatever currently is inside that non-initialised variable. `sec` at this point is for example not guaranteed to be 0. So the `else if` does not trigger and we end up in `else {}`.

So we end up executing the `printf()` at the end of the program with a still uninitialised `sec`. And that is unlikely to satisfy the judge.

To solve the problem, you need to initialise `sec`. Initialising to 0 might work, but actually you need to use the lowest possible input value.
Since you chose `int`, instead of `unsigned int`, I assume that 0 is NOT the lowest possible value. But you would have to quote the assignment/challenge to allow determining the lowest possible value. So you need to find that out yourself in order to make a solution code.

Alernatively, you can analyse the first input values to initialise `max` and `sec` (need to watch them coming in until you get two distinct values; credits to Aconcagua).
Usually it is however easier to determine the lowest possible value from requirements or the lowest possible `int` value from your environment.
At some level of nitpicking, you need to know the lowest possible value anyway, in order to select the correct data type for your implementation.  I.e. even with analysing the first two values, you might fail for selecting the most narrow data type.

In case you "successfully" (as judged by the challenge) use 0 to initialise `sec`, try the input `2 1 -1`.
It should fail.
Then try to find in your challenge/assignment description a reason why using 0 is allowed. It should be there, otherwise find a different challenge site to improve your coding skills.

Comment: *'you can analyse the first two input values to initialise max and sec'* – not necessarily. If first two values are equal and all subsequent ones smaller, we'd still get incorrect result (apparently QA is looking for second largest *distinct* value...).

Comment: thankyou so much. initializing sec with 0 solved my problem.

Comment: It only solved the problem because you were lucky. I think I'd have provided test inputs like 2 1 -1 in order to trip you up with that assumption. The answer should of course be -1, as the second highest among the 2 inputs. Try it, you will see. Please edit the question to show your reasons for selecting 0, e.g. quotes from the challenge which guarantee that there will not be negative input. There must be something there, otherwise you could not get past good tests....

Answer (score 2):

Consider sequence 2, 12, 10 (leaving out surrounding code):

```
int sec;       // unitialised!!!
max = a;       // 12
if(b > max)    // b got 10, so false!
{
    sec = max; // this code is not hit! (b remains uninitalised)
    max = b;
}
else if(b < max && b > sec)
//                      ^ comparing against uninitialised
//                        -> UNDEFINED BEHAVIOUR
```

You need to initialise `sec` appropriately, e. g. with `INT_MIN` (defined in `<limits.h>`); this is the minimal allowed value, with 32-bit `int` that would be a value of -2<sup>32 - 1</sup>, i. e. -2 147 483 648. Pretty unlikely anybody would enter that value, so you could use it as sentinel.

You even could initialise `max` with that value, then you woudn't need special handling for the first value:

```
int sec = INT_MIN, max = INT_MIN;
int n;
scanf("%d", &n); // you should check the return value, which is number of
                 // successfully scanned values, i. e. 1 in given case,
                 // to catch invalid user input!
// you might check value of n for being out of valid range, at very least < 0

while(n--) // you can do the decrement inside loop header already...
{
    // keep scope of variables as local as possible:
    int a;
    // scanf and comparisons as you had already
    // again don't forget to check scanf's return value
}
if(sec == INT_MAX)
{
    // likely hasn't been modified -> error, no second largest element
}
else
{
    // ...
}
```

Now what if you *do* expect user to give you the value of `INT_MIN` as input?

You could have a separate counter, initialised to 0, you increment in both of the two `if` branches inside the loop; if this counter is < 2 after the loop, you didn't get at least two distinct numbers...

Comment: :-) Like me you also do not provide copy-paste solution to use in the challenge. (Though at first I thought you did.)

Answer (score 0):

I liked how OP initialized `max` with the first input value.

This brought me to the idea that the same can be done for `sec`.
(The value of `max` is a nice indicator that `sec` could not be determined whatever `max` contains. In regular case, `max` and `sec` can never be equal.)

Hence, one possibility is to initialize `max` *and* `sec` with the first input
and use `max != sec` as indicator whether `sec` has been written afterwards at all.

Demo:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  /* read number of inputs */
  int n;
  if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n < 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR!\n");
    return -1;
  }
  /* read 1st input */
  int max;
  if (scanf("%d", &max) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR!\n");
    return -1;
  }
  --n;
  int sec = max;
  /* read other input */
  while (n--) {
    int a;
    if (scanf("%d", &a) != 1) {
      fprintf(stderr, "ERROR!\n");
      return -1;
    }
    if (max < a) { sec = max; max = a; }
    else if (sec == max || (sec < a && a < max)) sec = a;
  }
  /* evaluate result */
  if (sec == max) {
    puts("No second largest value occurred!\n");
  } else printf("%d\n", sec);
  /* done */
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ gcc -std=c11 -O2 -Wall -pedantic main.c
$ echo -e "3 3 4 5" | ./a.out
4
$ echo -e "3 3 5 4" | ./a.out
4
$ echo -e "3 4 3 5" | ./a.out
4
$ echo -e "3 4 5 3" | ./a.out
4
$ echo -e "3 5 3 4" | ./a.out
4
$ echo -e "3 5 4 3" | ./a.out
4
$ # edge case:
$ echo -e "2 3 3" | ./a.out
No second largest value occurred!
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8345657e92b6b30f)</kbd>

Comment: Disadvantage now is, though, that we need to check for `sec == max` in *each* loop iteration...